# What is the best way to read application-context.xml in Spring MVC application, Is it by adding in init-param tag or by adding in context-param tag?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

In few applications I see application-context file being read via init-param and in few via context-param. My intention is to know which one to use when.

Answer (score 0):

after all it dependence on you project requirement

1) if you want to set the access scope of data then use the  .if  you declare anything inside  is only accessible only for that particular servlet. The init-param is declared inside the  tag.

2) if you want to **access the data whole application** or anywhere in the application then you must go with

if you agree with this hit the up-arrow button